# Kotlin After 60 Second stopping the taking voice record

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying a take record in maximum 60 second in kotlin

```
object :  CountDownTimer(60000,1000) {
    override fun onFinish(){
        timeText.text = "Time's Fİnish!"

        handler.removeCallbacks(runnbale)
        for (button2 in runnable ){
            button2.stop()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error on object and runnable

```
Error:(70, 13) Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract 
    base class member public abstract fun onTick(p0: Long): Unit defined in 
    android.os.CountDownTimer
Error:(75, 37) Unresolved reference: runnable
```

Comment: The object `does not implement abstract 
 base class member public abstract fun onTick(p0: Long): Unit defined in 
android.os.CountDownTimer`. CountDownTimer needs both methods, onFinish and onTick.

Comment: Are you sure CountDownTimer is the right tool? You need to stop the recording *once after 60 seconds passed*. You don't need to execute something *once every second for one minute*.

Comment: @EugenPechanec thank you bro i solved the error on object. But i'm not sure the CountdownTimer is the right tool or not.. Actually CountDownTimer is just showing the users how many times they have but how can i stopped the taking record automatically after 60 sec.